# How to map C function to LLVM IR?

Tags: c, parsing, llvm, llvm-ir

I got a requirement in which i have a c file and i am generating LLVM IR for the same. From the generated LLVM IR for each instruction i am calculating how many cycles it will take to execute, now my problem is how can i trace back the same to the c code and displays the particular c code block(say function) took calculated number of cycles(Which i am actually calculating from the generated LLVM IR code).

I have a c code as below:

```
int arithmeticOperations(int x, int y)
{
    int aa, ab, ac, ad;
    if(x>10)
    {
        aa = x+y;
        ab = x-y;
        for(x = 1; x <= aa; ++x)
        {
            y += x;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ac = x*y;
        ad = x/y;       
    }
    return aa * ab * ac * ad;
}

void arithmeticOperationsPart2(int x, int y)
{
    int aa, ab, ac, ad;
    if(x>10)
    {
        aa = x+y;
        ab = x-y;
    }
    else
    {
        ac = x*y;
        ad = x/y;       
    }
}

int main()
{
    arithmeticOperations(35, 7);
    arithmeticOperationsPart2(35, 7);
}
```

I am creating LLVM IR using command:

```
clang -Os -S -emit-llvm addition.c
```

This output addition.ll file as below:

```
; ModuleID = 'addition.c'
source_filename = "addition.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:w-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc18.0.0"

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind optsize readnone uwtable
define i32 @arithmeticOperations(i32, i32) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %3 = icmp sgt i32 %0, 10
  br i1 %3, label %4, label %7

; <label>:4:                                      ; preds = %2
  %5 = add nsw i32 %1, %0
  %6 = sub nsw i32 %0, %1
  br label %10

; <label>:7:                                      ; preds = %2
  %8 = mul nsw i32 %1, %0
  %9 = sdiv i32 %0, %1
  br label %10

; <label>:10:                                     ; preds = %4, %7
  %11 = phi i32 [ undef, %7 ], [ %5, %4 ]
  %12 = phi i32 [ undef, %7 ], [ %6, %4 ]
  %13 = phi i32 [ %8, %7 ], [ undef, %4 ]
  %14 = phi i32 [ %9, %7 ], [ undef, %4 ]
  %15 = mul nsw i32 %12, %11
  %16 = mul nsw i32 %15, %13
  %17 = mul nsw i32 %16, %14
  ret i32 %17
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind optsize readnone uwtable
define void @arithmeticOperationsPart2(i32, i32) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind optsize readnone uwtable
define i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { norecurse nounwind optsize readnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!1 = !{!"clang version 5.0.0 (trunk 302984) (llvm/trunk 302983)"}
```

Now i want to filter what LLVM code corresponds to the c source code it generated.(Say specific to a function)

For example(currently i want to filter the c function `arithmeticOperations` ):

```
  %3 = icmp sgt i32 %0, 10
  br i1 %3, label %4, label %7

; <label>:4:                                      ; preds = %2
  %5 = add nsw i32 %1, %0
  %6 = sub nsw i32 %0, %1
  br label %10

; <label>:7:                                      ; preds = %2
  %8 = mul nsw i32 %1, %0
  %9 = sdiv i32 %0, %1
  br label %10

; <label>:10:                                     ; preds = %4, %7
  %11 = phi i32 [ undef, %7 ], [ %5, %4 ]
  %12 = phi i32 [ undef, %7 ], [ %6, %4 ]
  %13 = phi i32 [ %8, %7 ], [ undef, %4 ]
  %14 = phi i32 [ %9, %7 ], [ undef, %4 ]
  %15 = mul nsw i32 %12, %11
  %16 = mul nsw i32 %15, %13
  %17 = mul nsw i32 %16, %14
  ret i32 %17
```

corresponds to the below part of the c code:

```
int aa, ab, ac, ad;
    if(x>10)
    {
        aa = x+y;
        ab = x-y;
        for(x = 1; x <= aa; ++x)
        {
            y += x;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ac = x*y;
        ad = x/y;       
    }
    return aa * ab * ac * ad;
```

Comment: Why not generate the assembly list file from the C or LLVM IR and get the instruction count for your platform architecture auto-magically?

Comment: @FrankC.: Thanks for your reply, I didn't quite get that, will the instruction count generated form LLVM IR will be generic for all targets?

Comment: When you generate the assembler listing from the LLVM-IR the instruction set would be platform architecture specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell clang to emit debug info by adding the -g flag:

```
clang -Os -S -emit-llvm -g addition.c
```

Then you will find plenty of information about which instruction corresponds to which original line in your ll file.

For example the start of the `arithmeticOperations` function is translated as follows, with the lines ending in `!dgb !<number>` referring to debug information entries:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind optsize readnone uwtable
define i32 @arithmeticOperations(i32 %x, i32 %y) local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !7 {
entry:
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 %y, i64 0, metadata !12, metadata !18), !dbg !19
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 %x, i64 0, metadata !13, metadata !18), !dbg !20
  %cmp = icmp sgt i32 %x, 10, !dbg !21
  br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.else, !dbg !23
```

Towards the end of the file there will be many "DILocation" entries telling you where the corresponding source code was:

```
...
!19 = !DILocation(line: 1, column: 37, scope: !7)
!20 = !DILocation(line: 1, column: 30, scope: !7)
!21 = !DILocation(line: 4, column: 9, scope: !22)
!22 = distinct !DILexicalBlock(scope: !7, file: !1, line: 4, column: 8)
!23 = !DILocation(line: 4, column: 8, scope: !7)
```

So if you are interested where this line came from:

```
%cmp = icmp sgt i32 %x, 10, !dbg !21
```

You have to look for the debug entry !21:

```
!21 = !DILocation(line: 4, column: 9, scope: !22)
```

And indeed, line 9 is where the if is:

```
9:    if(x>10)
```

Clangs debug info is so precise it even points to the '>' operator.

Comment: One point to note is optimizations are passes are not required to preserve the debug info. So -g should be used only with -O0 or equivalent.

Comment: @PaulR: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is a good piece of information for me, but what I am looking for is to automate the process. With this approach, i have to write again a parser to match debug info lines to the source code.

Comment: @PaulR: I did some research and found few parser but none are up to date, so thanks for your approach using which I can manipulate the file and extract information.